# User.Identity.Name is empty when API is called through Azure API Management

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

**If I call my API from a client (example is a native Console app) through API Management, my User.Identity.Name is empty and IsAuthenticated is False in the back-end API.**

If I call my API through the API Management portal webpage (the Try It test portal), my server-side API code is able to see my User.Identity (User.Identity.Name, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated).

On my client side, I am getting a token and then calling an API that is exposed via Azure API Management.

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};

client = new HttpClient(handler);
authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AADInstance);

PlatformParameters platformParameters = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto);
AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiResourceId, clientId, redirectUrl, platformParameters);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(authResult.AccessTokenType, authResult.AccessToken);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("Keep-Alive");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "...");

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);

var response = await GetResponseAsync(baseAddress + "Diagnostics");
```

On the server, I am trying to get the User.Identity that called the API (my API, of course, doesn't know that it is being called through the API Management portal). The User.Identity.Name is empty, the AuthenticationType is empty, the IsAuthenticated flag is False. These values are populated correctly if I call my API via the API Management portal "Try It" function.

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
userName = User.Identity.Name; //is empty
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
items.Add($"Authentication Type: '{claimsIdentity.AuthenticationType}'"); // is empty
items.Add($"Is Authenticated: {claimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated}"); // is False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the resource ID that was passed in as part of the request for the Bearer token. It must be the **App ID URI of the backend API**, not the API Management portal.

Answer (score 0):

API Management by default does not touch the Authorization header, so if the client is sending a JWT token, then the backend should receive it untouched.

You could try using the validate-jwt policy in APIM to verify that the token that the client is sending you is actually valid.

Are you using the same clientId for your console client as you used to setup the Try It portal?  If not, has the console clientId been authorized against the backend in AAD?

Are you doing https to the backend from APIM?  Without https, the credentials may be ignored.

Comment: I'm not sure what "clientID" the Try It portal is using. It only lists the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key, Authorization Bearer token, and the subscription key. I have authorized the "clientID" of the Console application in AAD. I am using HTTPs (both the Web Service URL and the Web API URL scheme are set to HTTPs). I haven't tried to set a Validate JWT policy yet since I know via my code that I am sending a bearer token.